# How to do a major version upgrade for Aurora Postgres in CloudFormation with custom Parameter Groups?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

## Issue

I am trying to do a major version upgrade from Aurora Postgres 10.14 to 11.9 using Cloudformation. My template creates a `DBCluster`, a `DBInstance`, a `DBClusterParameterGroup` and a `DBParameterGroup`.

The problem is that when I try to update the stack and change the `EngineVersion` property for `DBCluster` from `10.14` to `11.9` and change the `Family` property for `DBClusterParameterGroup` and `DBParameterGroup` from `aurora-postgresql10` to `aurora-postgresql11`, I get this error in CloudFormation:

## Error

> The following parameters are not defined for the specified group: enable_partitionwise_aggregate, enable_parallel_append, enable_partition_pruning, vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor, pg_bigm.last_update, apg_enable_semijoin_push_down, parallel_leader_participation, pg_bigm.enable_recheck, pg_bigm.gin_key_limit, max_parallel_maintenance_workers, pg_bigm.similarity_limit, enable_parallel_hash, enable_partitionwise_join (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue)

I think this is because, according to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html#cfn-rds-dbclusterparametergroup-family) for RDS Parameter Groups:

> The DB cluster parameter group family can't be changed when updating a DB cluster parameter group

So even though I am trying to update the `Family` property for `DBClusterParameterGroup` and `DBParameterGroup`, CloudFormation simply ignores that, and so it is trying to apply the `aurora-postgresql10` Parameter group Family `aurora-postgresql10` to a database now trying to run Aurora Postgres 11.9

## What I've tried

- Updating the `Description` property for
  DBClusterParameterGroup`and`DBParameterGroup`to include a reference to the`pEngineVersion` parameter, as the AWS Documentation
  says that will trigger a Replacement, but it does not actually do
  this, and so I get the same error
- Manually adding the parameters listed in the error to `DBParameterGroup` before running update. Got error "Unmodifiable DB Parameter: pg_bigm.last_update"

The only workaround I have found is clunky:

1. Manually update the database version in the console from 10.14 to 11.9, and change the `DB cluster parameter group` and `Parameter group` both to `default.aurora-postgresql11` as well
2. Comment out the code for `DBClusterParameterGroup` and  `DBParameterGroup` and update the stack with the updated `EngineVersion` `11.9` for `DBCluster`
3. Uncomment out the code for `DBClusterParameterGroup` and `DBParameterGroup` and update the stack again with the correct `Family` property `aurora-postgresql11` on `DBClusterParameterGroup` and `DBParameterGroup`. Now the database is updated, it is using the custom parameter groups, and the stack is not drifting

## Code

```
Parameters:

  pEngineVersion:
    Type: String
    #currently '10.14'
    #trying to change to '11.9'
  pFamily:
    Type: String
    #currently 'aurora-postgresql10'
    #trying to change to 'aurora-postgresql11'

Resources:

  DBClusterParamGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'AuroraDBClusterParamGroup-${AWS::Region}'
      Family: !Ref pFamily
      Parameters:
        application_name: "App name"
        log_statement: all
        log_min_duration_statement: 0

  DBParamGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'AuroraDBParamGroup-${AWS::Region}'
      Family: !Ref pFamily
      Parameters:
        max_connections: 1000

  AuroraDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      EngineVersion: !Ref pEngineVersion
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref 'DBClusterParamGroup'
      #snipping unneccesary code#

  AuroraDBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBParameterGroupName: !Ref 'DBParamGroup'
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref 'AuroraDBCluster'
      #snipping unneccesary code#
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

This method worked for me (I've modified some things slightly to post in a public forum) **EDIT**: I have updated this to use the Blue/Green solution now that I have had the chance to test it.

```
Parameters:
[...]
  DBEngineVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: "Choices are engine versions from Postgres 9/10/11, only newest and legacy deployed in Prod versions"
    Default: 11.7
    AllowedValues:
      - 9.6.18
      - 10.7
      - 10.14
      - 11.7
  MajorVersionUpgrade:
    Type: String
    Description: Swap this between 'Blue' or 'Green' if we are doing a Major version upgrade
    Default: Blue
    AllowedValues:
      - Blue
      - Green

Conditions:
  BlueDeployment: !Equals [!Ref MajorVersionUpgrade, "Blue"]
  GreenDeployment: !Equals [!Ref MajorVersionUpgrade, "Green"]
  
Mappings:
  EngineToPGFamily:
    "9.6.18":
      PGFamily: aurora-postgresql9.6
    "10.7":
      PGFamily: aurora-postgresql10
    "10.14":
      PGFamily: aurora-postgresql10
    "11.7":
      PGFamily: aurora-postgresql11

  ##### Keep parameters of both versions in sync ####
  DBClusterParameterGroupBlue: #Keep parameters of both versions in sync
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup"
    Condition: BlueDeployment
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub "Postgres Cluster Parameter Group for ${InfrastructureStackName}"
      Family: !FindInMap ['EngineToPGFamily', !Ref 'DBEngineVersion', 'PGFamily']
      Parameters:
        client_encoding: UTF8
        idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 60000
  DBClusterParameterGroupGreen:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup"
    Condition: GreenDeployment
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub "Postgres Cluster Parameter Group for ${InfrastructureStackName}"
      Family: !FindInMap ['EngineToPGFamily', !Ref 'DBEngineVersion', 'PGFamily']
      Parameters:
        client_encoding: UTF8
        idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 60000

  DBCluster:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-cluster"
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !If [GreenDeployment, !Ref DBClusterParameterGroupGreen, !Ref DBClusterParameterGroupBlue]
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
[...]
  DBInstance1:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref DBCluster
      EngineVersion: !Ref DBEngineVersion
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
[...]

  DBInstance2:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref DBCluster
      EngineVersion: !Ref DBEngineVersion
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
[...]
```

## Usage and Methodology

This method will create a new ClusterParameterGroup that will be used during the upgrade (when doing a Major version upgrade), and clean up the original group when the upgrade is done.  The advantage to this solution is that there is no version hardcoding in the group and the same template can be used for continuous lifecycle updates without additional changes needed (aside from desired `Parameters` updates).

### Initial Setup

Initially, leave **MajorVersionUpgrade** set to **Blue** and the conditions will ensure that only the Blue ParameterGroup is created using the proper DB family.

### Performing a Major Version Upgrade

Update the stack and set the **DBEngineVersion** to the ***new major version*** and **MajorVersionUpgrade** to **Green** if it is *currently Blue* (or **Blue** if it is *currently Green*).  CloudFormation will:

1. Start by creating the new resources (which is the new parameter group referencing the new version)
2. Then it will update the Cluster and point to that new group
3. Finally, it will delete the old ParameterGroup (referncing the old version) during the cleanup phase since the Blue/Green Condition for that group no longer evaluates to true.

## Important notes

1. The `Parameters` in both parameter groups must manually kept in sync
2. Obviously, update the `DBEngineVersion` `AllowedValues` list with versions as needed, just be sure to update the `EngineToPGFamily` `Mappings` to have a valid Postgres family value for that Engine version
3. Special care must be paid when implementing `Parameters` that are new to a DB Major version and don't exist in an older version, I have not tested this

Comment: I can confirm a Blue / Green configuration will work but it will fail with the same eorr if a `DBParameterGroupName` is specified on the resource `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`. You can find a test CloudFormation template here https://repost.aws/questions/QUZ5wjdoPuS36L5rd-tp5vKQ

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you cannot change the family on a DB Parameter Group that already has been created. That is why you get the error about the missing parameters, which isn't a great error response by AWS given the root cause.

Since DB Parameter Groups can be replaced without having to replace the DB Instance, you should change the Logical ID of the DB Parameter Group so it is detected as a new resource by CloudFormation, and removes the old v10 DB Parameter Group.

Example using your code:

```
Parameters:

  pEngineVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: '11.9'
    #currently '10.14'
    #trying to change to '11.9'
  pFamily:
    Type: String
    Default: 'aurora-postgresql11'
    #currently 'aurora-postgresql10'
    #trying to change to 'aurora-postgresql11'

Resources:

  DBClusterParamGroup11:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'AuroraDBClusterParamGroup-${AWS::Region}'
      Family: !Ref pFamily
      Parameters:
        application_name: "App name"
        log_statement: all
        log_min_duration_statement: 0

  DBParamGroup11:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub 'AuroraDBParamGroup-${AWS::Region}'
      Family: !Ref pFamily
      Parameters:
        max_connections: 1000

  AuroraDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      EngineVersion: !Ref pEngineVersion
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref 'DBClusterParamGroup'
      #snipping unneccesary code#

  AuroraDBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBParameterGroupName: !Ref 'DBParamGroup'
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref 'AuroraDBCluster'
      #snipping unneccesary code#
```

Notice how I renamed DBParamGroup to DBParamGroup11 and DBClusterParamGroup to DBClusterParamGroup11.